# Passing data from an Activity to a fragment that has no onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-bundle

Is it possible to pass data from an Activity using Bundle to a Fragment that has no OnCreate

Comment: you can implement onCreate in fragment: check here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: fragment has a onCreate() but you can not pass data from activity you need  eventbus or interface approach.

Comment: no,is impossible

Comment: Its not necessary to have onCreate method in fragment to get passed data. You can get data in fragment by using getArguments() in any of fragment lifecycle method after it attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompactActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fragment = new SampleFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            args.putInt("sample_int", 1);

            fragment.setArguments(args);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                 .add(R.id.container, fragment)
                 .commit();
        }
    }
}



public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        if (args != null) {
            int sampleInt = args.getInt("sample_int", -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Activity, you send data with intent as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```